# uniqueEntity message

Tags: symfony

i've created a form with symfony 2, and i check if the fields are unique with the UniqueEntity constraint. But i want the fields "firstname", "name" to appear in the message, like:

"Mark Blaze already exists!" rather than "this person already exists!"

can someone help?

part of the form builder

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder

            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('name')
```

Entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="InviteRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"firstname","name"}, message="this person already exists!")
 */
class Invite {
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
     */
    private $name;
```

twig file

```
   {{ form_start(form) }}        

{{ form_errors(form) }}
{% spaceless %}
        <div class="control-group">
            {{ form_label(form.firstname, 'firstname *', { 'label_attr': { 'class':'control-label'} }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.firstname) }}
            <div class="controls">
                {{ form_widget(form.firstname) }}
                {% if form.vars.help is defined %}
                    <span class="help-block">{{ form.vars.help }}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
         </div>
    {% endspaceless %}

    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="control-group">
            {{ form_label(form.name, 'name *', { 'label_attr': { 'class':'control-label'} }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
            <div class="controls">
                {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
                {% if form.vars.help is defined %}
                    <span class="help-block">{{ form.vars.help }}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
```

Much thanks

Comment: In the worst case, you can implement your own [Custom Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can use this in the error message {{ value }} and this will represent the sent value. I use this in the emailconstraint so, `'The {{ value }} email address already in use'`.
I think this would work for you too.

I rechecked your constraint and sadly, there you don't have the option to set a dynamic value. What I posted earlier was a solution for a really symfony validation and this constraint is part of doctrine. But any time, you can create your own constraint, if you want to fulfil your special needs:
    $this->context->addViolationAt($errorPath, $constraint->message, array(), $criteria[$fields[0]]);

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, i've tried your solution like this:                                                                   @UniqueEntity(fields={"mail"}, message="{{ mail }} already exists")                                                           the unique Entity constraint works perfectly but it doesn't show the sent email. it shows: {{ mail }} already exists. could you show me the entire code that works for you? maybe it's not the same.

Comment: I have what i copied in, the name of the variable has to be {{ value }}

Comment: @ghostika - Putting `{{ value }}` in the message does not work for me. Is there some trick?